# Google Site Search - cookie?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I am using Google Site Search on a website.
On the site there is a cookie prompter, that asks the user to accept cookies, before we start using them. This is working fine. However, after we have implemented Google Search, it turns out that Google also has a couple of cookies.

My question is; how do we make Google not use these cookies until the user have accepted it (or another parameter).

The following basic example, will make Google create 2 cookies:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var cx = '012:345'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Any ideas how to get around/fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The code above is responsible for loading the script google.com/cse.js. Instead of exeuting the function immediately, you can wait till user accepted the cookies policy:

```
<script>
var loadScript = function() {
  var cx = '012:345'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
};

// Here ask user for cookies etc.

// Then load script.
loadScript();
</script>

<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```